# How can I make fft from a signal, using ipp library in c++?

Tags: c++, fft, intel-ipp

I am new in IPP Intel and I want to make fft from a signal, using ipp library in c++?
I configure ipp in my project well.
Can anybody help me?

thanks

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the existing example into IPP package: /examples/components/examples_core/ipp_fft/..src. This example shows how to use the Intel® IPP image linear transforms: Fourier transforms (fast and discrete) and discrete cosine transform (DCT).